# Responsive JavaScript: execute code only for small device width

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have some simple JavaScript (embedded in an event) that I want to fire only for small devices. Phones, etc...

Currently I'm doing

```
if ($(window).width() < 606) {
  do_things();
}
```

But this feels clunky. Is there a way to only execute this for devices smaller than a certain breakpoint (aside from just setting an earlier variable)? Ideally something that works with my CSS breakpoints.

I'm using Bootstrap, so there may be an easy option that utilizes that.

Comment: You can't just set a variable because the width can change at any time on some devices. (For example, rotate a phone to landscape.)

Comment: Check out...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser

Comment: @Colyn1337 Jesus, user agent sniffing, really?

Comment: wrap it in $(window).resize(); and you are good to go!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As crude as your code might look to you, this is actually in a nutshell what a media query is.  If you look at the source for [responsive.js](http://www.responsivejs.com/) (JS lib that adds media query support to older browsers) it includes this function:

```
function getDeviceWidth() {
    if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
        //Non-IE
        return window.innerWidth;
    } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
        //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
        return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
        //IE 4 compatible
        return document.body.clientWidth;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

While this is a more complete approach to detecting device width (and this is combined with an `onResize` event handler to detect things like rotation), it is fundamentally what you are doing.